# Filter by column to column sum or operator in BreezeJS

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, filtering, breeze

If I have a table with two numeric columns, say X and Y, and need to retrieve rows where say X > Y. How can I achieve this using BreezeJS? All examples I've come across are only capable of comparing columns to a fixed value so far.

**Edit:**
I tried using `.where("Id", "==", "Id")` just for testing and got the following error:

*Query failed: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'.*

To confirm that there were no errors with the query itself I tried `.where("Id", "==", 1)` and it went through.

Any clue on this anyone?

Answer (score 1):

When Breeze executes a query, it checks the string on the right hand side of the predicate to determine if it is a property name instead of a literal and by default will chose the to treat the value as a property if a property of the same name exists on the type being queried. So if 'qtyOrdered' and 'qtyAvailable' are both properties of the 'Order' type then the following is supported.

```
  var query = EntityQuery.from("Order").where("qtyOrdered", ">", "qtyAvailable");
```

This behavior can also be overridden ( sometimes necessary for string columns) but is rarely needed.

Comment: This is what I did initially but got this error message: "Query failed: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Decimal' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'LessThan'.". I also made sure the column names matched. Both are decimals one of them is nullable.

Comment: Make sure that both names are 'client' side names if you are using a namingConvention like 'camelCasing'. If this is correct,  then check your entityType metadata by calling entityType.getProperty for both property names and check that you get a dataProperty with the expected data types for both calls.

Comment: Actually .where("Id", "==", 1) works fine but not .where("Id", "==", "Id"). Both wouldn't work if there was a name mismatch. Not sure how I can access entityType.getProperty though. Can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Ok I can confirm that there are no issues with property 'Id' from data I retrieved through manager.metadataStore.getEntityType('MyTable').getProperty('Id'). It doesn't work outside the query callback method but I guess that's normal. Type checking is no longer an issue now since the columns are the same on both sides. I'm completely lost now. Is there anything else I might have missed?

Comment: I'll try to create some additional tests to see if I can repro your issue.  Or if you could create a failing test using the DocCode sample in the Breeze.js.samples repo and post it here or on the Git repo.

Comment: I updated to the latest version and I'm still getting the same problem with .where("Id", "==", "Id") while .where("Id", "==", 1) works just fine. That's definitely a bug. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: I'll try to look at it later this week.